# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, High Volume Portal Users cannot have a user role - Test class

Tags: apex, class, failing-tests

The user role created below is not 'High volume Portal User' but, still production deployment validation fails with error "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, High Volume Portal Users cannot have a user role". Can someone help with this please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue got resolved by commenting out userRoleId assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You should not define role for community users. Communities users get their roles automatically from their account. Try removing the UserRoleId field from User instantiation statement.

Comment: Hi Ashish, thanks for your response. When removed, the same test class fails saying " Portal account owner" must have role.

Comment: Check if user which is active in the context has a role assigned. User which is owner of the account must have a role to create a community user

Comment: As I can see you are using currently active user in System.runAs, so you should assign role to your user and make sure your deployment user has a role when you move the code to next environments